# How can I set this Url in Nodejs By Express Router

Tags: node.js, express, router

I have a url like this:

```
localhost:3000/HotDataWindow_Region.html?callback=jsonp1416904898691&datatype=Region
```

How to set the router to get it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure you have indicated the exact problem you are facing but it is possible to serve raw html from an express router using the sendFile method of the response object.

1. get the pathname of your request - the bit between the slash after port (if exist) and the question mark that starts the query string.  You may use the url module or any alternative.
2. get the query string from the url and do whatever you want with it.
3. create an options object literal and pass some options e.g. the location of the raw html file relative to where the executing javaScript is located
4. use sendFile to render the raw html and handle errors the way you want - the API is here: http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendfile

See a sample below which may get you started if it helps:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    url = require ('url');
    router = express.Router();
router.get('/index.html', function(req, res){
    var options = {
        root: __dirname + '/html/' //assuming your raw html files are kept in /html sub folder
    }; 
    var fileName = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    var query = url.parse(req.url).query; // do whatever with the query string(s)
    res.sendFile(fileName, options, function(error){
        //handle your error anyway you want
    });
});
app.use('/', router);
app.listen(3900);
```

However, since you have query strings in you sample url, I would imagine you need a templating engine rather than serving raw html file!

I hope you can move in the right direction.

SO1

Comment: thank you very much! i use express ejs template ,and i want get the request and response json string ,but ,i use express router to get that url,but it can't get this reueqst.....

Comment: I still don't get exactly what you want to achieve, do you mean you want to retrieve the bits after the ? mark as a json object?